# Установить RabbitMQ для Laravel 5.8. Ошибка composer - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer, rabbitmq

Всем заглянувшим, доброго времени суток!

Сам сервер запускается и работает нормально(Docker).
Но при добавлении данной [либы](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) через composer `composer require vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` получаю исключения.

```
   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
    - Installation request for vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq 6.0.3 -> satisfiable by vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq[v6.0.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
    - vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq v6.0.3 requires illuminate/queue 5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5
.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/queue v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22,
v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.38, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "yoeunes/toastr": "^1.2",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

---

`Composer version 1.10.8 2020-06-24 21:23:30`

По цепочке появляется много зависимостей, что кажется странным. Подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в кэше. Т.е. конфиг Laravel-я был закеширован!

Команды

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

решили вопрос.